# Implementing Unity Global Menu

Tags: unity, application-development, python, appmenu

I'm working on a desktop (like XFCE) as a private project, and I would like to implement the Unity Global Menu in my desktop using python. I've looked at the [Dbusmenu API](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Dbusmenu_0.4/index.html) and even Unity's dbus "Registrar" itself and I'm  still lost. How do I go about implementing my own appmenu-indicator? Do I need to implement my own "AppMenuRegistrar" or can I reuse Ubuntu's libraries and services?